# Xamarin Forms: Grid increasing row heights for all rows on single word wrap

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms view, when one row in a grid has a word wrap, it's increasing the row height for all other rows as well.  What property can I change to ensure only the affected row has increased row height?

Normal styling:

[image]

Styling after wrap on 'Location':

[image]

XAML:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="auctions:VehicleViewModel">
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActivitySpinner" IsRunning="True" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Error}" StyleClass="Error" IsVisible="{Binding ErrorVisible}" />
        
        <Label Text="Basic Details" StyleClass="HeaderGreen" IsVisible="{Binding IsNotBusy}" />
        <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsNotBusy}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Model" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.VehicleModel}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
            <Label Text="Registration" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.Registration}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Label Text="Year" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.Year}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
            <Label Text="Mileage (Kms)" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.Odometer}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
            <Label Text="Supplier" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.Supplier}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
            <Label Text="Location" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.Location}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" />
            <Label Text="Gearbox" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.GearboxType}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" />
            <Label Text="Colour" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.Colour}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" />
            <Label Text="Interior Colour" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.InteriorColour}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" />
            <Label Text="Financed By" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.FinancedBy}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" />
            <Label Text="Trade Price" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="10" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.TradePrice, Converter={StaticResource Currency}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" />
            <Label Text="Retail Price" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="11" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.RetailPrice, Converter={StaticResource Currency}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" />
            <Label Text="New Price" StyleClass="Label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="12" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Vehicle.NewPrice, Converter={StaticResource Currency}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="12" />
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with defining `Auto` height:

```
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Here's the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) for Xamarin.Forms Grid, check the *Rows and columns* paragraph.
As stated in the docs, you shold try to ensure that as few rows as possible are set to Auto size. So, use this only for the affected rows.

Comment: That solves the issue, thanks. The documents state that `Auto` should be avoided due to the increase in calculations, but I would really expect this to be the default behaviour, like it is with HTML.

Comment: @Savage Btw, could do this in [a simple way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#simplify-row-and-column-definitions) since XF 4.7.

Comment: Thanks @Shaw. I hate that I even have to have definitions - wish it was freeform like HTML.

Comment: @Savage Well, could do a bit with CSS, [docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/), not sure helps.